# Can someone who possibly already did a mitzva cover another such person with the b'racha?

Tags: halacha, blessing, motzi-yedei-chovato, safek

As codified in *Mishna B'rura* 592 and elsewhere, we allow someone who has already fulfilled a *mitzva* to exempt another in the *b'racha* recited for it — though we try to avoid it where feasible. For example, someone who has read or heard the *m'gila* (*Ester*) already can recite the *b'rachos* over the *m'gila* for someone else about to hear the *m'gila*, though we prefer the latter recite them instead. The same is true <sup>[citation needed]</sup> for a *b'racha* which **is** a *mitzva*, such as *kidush l'vana*.

Suppose someone, call him *R'uven*, is **unsure** whether he's fulfilled his obligation, say of reading *m'gila* or saying *kidush l'vana*. Then common practice is that he not recite the *b'rachos* himself but listen to another who is **surely** still obligated and fulfill his obligation that way. Now suppose *Shim'on* is also unsure whether he's fulfilled his obligation (and his doubt is independent of *R'uven*'s). Consider: There's uncertainty about *R'uven*'s obligation to recite the *b'racha*, and there's uncertainty about *Shim'on*'s; there's a double uncertainty (*s'fek s'feka*) whether **both** are not obligated to recite the *b'racha*, so we should be able to assume at least one **is** obligated. In that case, one of them should be able to recite the *b'racha* for the both of them, in accordance with the principle outlined in my first paragraph. (This, assuming there's no one around who is surely obligated and can say the *b'racha* for *R'uven* and *Shim'on*.)

I wonder whether there's anything wrong with that argument, and whether any *pos'kim* have used or rejected it.

Comment: I wonder why you are asking this during Sefirat HaOmer...

Comment: @DoubleAA, the truth is, this is not so relevant to _s'fira_, because we hold any _safek_ (not just a _s'fek s'feka_) whether you counted allows you to continue _s'fira_ with a _b'racha_. (But CYLOR.) But, yes, _s'fira_ brought this question to mind.

Comment: Adderabba. We hold you need a _s'fek s'feka_ as well, just the first safek is very easy to come by. Meaning if you have some other safek, it's very easy to find a friend to be your other safek.

Comment: Quite right, @DoubleAA.

Comment: Your initial assumptions are « R'uven, is unsure whether he's fulfilled his obligation » and « Shim'on is also unsure whether he's fulfilled his obligation » and then after your discussion you say « so we should be able to assume at least one is obligated ». 
IMHO the discussion does not change the initial assumptions. Both are unsure – neither is obligated!

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok How could neither be obligated??? Both are unsure if obligated. How come you can change the initial assumptions, but he can't?

Comment: @DoubleAA I meant "neither is definitely obligated".

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok And msh210 would agree to that. He saying that together we can net sufficient obligation to allow blessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although in *Hilchos Sefiras Ha'Omer* we find that one makes a bracha based on a sfek sfaka (Mishne Berura 489:38), in general one may not rely on a sfek sfakah to make a bracha ([Mishne Berura 215:20](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%95)).

Rav S.Z. Auerbach (*Halichos Shlomo, Pesach 11, note 24*) explains that with Sefiras Ha'Omer nearly all Poskim agree that one makes a bracha even if he forgot to count one day (disagreeing with the opinion of B'Hag). Therefore, in *that case* we permit the recitation of a bracha with a sfek sfaika)

Whether someone who may have forgotten to count one day may be *motzi* another who always counted there is some disagreement among Poskim if, according to B'Hag) he is considered *hayyav* in the mitzva but technically can't count (*Bais Halevi* cited in Har Tzvi 2:25) and therefore *can* make the bracha for someone else, or is *not hayyav* in the mitzva since he missed a day (Kaf Hachaim 489:91) and can't be *motzi* another.

See Dirshu Mishne Berurah (ibid) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

A can make a bracha for B's mitzva from the law of erivus - Guarantor - the fact that you have not done a mitzva is my problem, and I am obligated in your mitzva.

> `ערוך השולחן אורח חיים סימן רעג`
> קיי"ל דכל המצות יכול אדם להוציא אחרים
> אף על פי שהוא כבר יצא או שהוא לא יצא עדיין ולא דמי לברכת הנהנין שאינו
> יכול להוציא אחרים אא"כ גם הוא נהנה עמהם דמצוה שאני דכיון דעל השומעים
> מוטל חובת המצוה לקיים כל ישראל ערבים זה בזה ומוציא אחד את חבירו

As above - this is for obligations, and not for example food where you are not obligated to eat.

Your case is not a s'fek s'feka.  There is one sofek.  Is B still obligated in his mitzva.  It does not matter if A is or not, as Bs obligation falls on A if B has one.  And it does not fall on A if B does not.